Android Virtual Device is showing different BackgroundColor in a React Native App than real device
In my React native code, I specify my BackgroundColor like this
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: darkTheme.neutral50,
  },

The darkTheme.neutral50 is defined as #0a0a0a, which is the BackgroundColor on the real device, but on the AVD it just shows #000000, which is completely black. And that's not just for the BackgroundColor, but also for the gesture navigation bar. And since I want to develop on the emulator, I need to fix this problem.
The left device is the emulator and the right one the real device.
Picture of the devices

It seems that it's not the problem of the APK or Issue is not related to React Native but something to do with any android device.

could you change the color, can see if it happened with another color or not, maybe it might from screen color or any mode on device
